# Cron issue when installing components

Tags: magento2, cron

I am having a problem when i try to install component through web setup wizard.
My php version is 7.1.29
I am using Magento 2.3.2
In Step 1: Readiness Check i get the following result

Check Updater Application Availability
Updater application is available.

Check Cron Scripts
Cron script readiness check failed. Hide detail

Error from Updater Application Cron Script:

Found non-writable path(s):
/home/*********/public_html/magento/.github

For additional assistance, see cron scripts help.

Check Component Dependency
We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

For additional assistance, see component dependency help .

PHP Settings Check *
Your PHP settings are correct.

PHP Extensions Check
You meet 21 out of 21 PHP extensions requirements. Show detail

Can someone please assist me to resolve these 2 issues?

Comment: Any help please someone?

Comment: Noone knows how to resolve this issue?